# open/close connection in form

Tags: c#, sql

I have question regarding SQL connection open and close.
which one is better:

1. open connection in `form_load` event and close it in `form_closing` event.
2. open and close connection for each call.

of course sometime I need to read data, frequently.

Comment: I guess the number 2 is the mostly used by all experts :)

Answer (score 2):

In general, you should keep database connections open for a small a time as possible.

So, open and close each connection for every call, in a `using` block to ensure disposal.

I would add that **non** of this should be happening in the form at all - the form should be concerned with handling UI and UI events - opening and closing connections should happen in you [data access layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer).

Comment: Is it wisely to open and close connection, for example in an event that runs frequently?

Comment: @user422481 - It really depends on the details, but all else being equal, yes, it is. If you are expecting the _same_ values all the time, consider caching the result of the database call and using the cached version.

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you would better choose method 2
if you choose 1, may be cause other problems

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how/when you want to use the connection. However you should enable connection pooling which should mitigate opening and closing multiple connections by keeping connections available in a pool for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for second as the interaction with data base is not required all the time. Usually we load data and save data. Opening connection for long time is useful when there is intense interaction with database and open and closing connection is costly. The code for interaction with database should be separated from UI and should go in [data access layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer). You can make a separate library of classes which perform database operations or at least make classes for database in the same project.

> A general guild line for open connection is to open Open connections
>   as late as possible and  close connections as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

I'd definitely recommend opening and closing the connection on demand. Thanks to connection pooling opening a connection is fairly inexpensive and it means you don't have to deal with checking the connection every time you use it to make sure it is still open.

Answer (score 0):

You should absolutely go for number 2.
Especially in a form, where you don't know for how long the user will occupy the connection.

Remmber to use a Using statement when declaring the connection so you are sure that no matter what happens, the connection will be closed again.

Answer (score 0):

the best practice is to close your sqlconnection as soon as possible so use a sqlconnection with using (it implements an IDisposable interface) as follows:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        //
        // Open the SqlConnection.
        //
        con.Open();
              //do your process
            }
```